# Error: Int type cannot be converted to class

Tags: java, type-conversion, binary-search

United States Class

```
 public class UnitedStates
{
// instance variables
private ArrayList <State> states;

public UnitedStates()
{
   states = new ArrayList <State> ();


   readFile();
   printStates();

   searchStates();  
}

public void searchStates()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans = "y";
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("=====================");
    System.out.println("     Searching");
    System.out.println("=====================");

    while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter state -->");
        String stateName = keyboard.nextLine();

                    State state = binarySearch(stateName);

        if(state == null)
           System.out.println("State not found");
        else
        {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("State Name       = " + state.getName());
          System.out.println("State Capital    = " + state.getCapital());
          System.out.println("State Nickname   = " + state.getNickname());
          System.out.println("State Population = " + state.getPopulation());
          System.out.println(); 
        }


        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Search again[Y/N]?");
        ans = keyboard.nextLine();

    }
}

// Performs a binarySearch on states searching for key
// If key is found it returns the State object that
// corresponds to key; otherwise it returns -1
public State binarySearch(String key)
{
        int left = 0;
        int right = states.size() - 1;

        while(left <= right)
        {
            int midpoint = (left + right) / 2;

            int result = states.get(midpoint).compareTo(key);

            if(result == 0)
            {    
                return midpoint;
            }
            else if(result < 0)
            {
                left = midpoint + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                right = midpoint - 1;
            }

}
        return -1;
    }

public void printStates()
{
    for(State s : states)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-15s", s.getName());
        System.out.printf("%-15s", s.getCapital());
        System.out.printf("%-25s", s.getNickname());
        System.out.printf("%10s\n", s.getPopulation()); 
    }
}

public void readFile()
{
    Scanner scan = null;
    try
    {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("states.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not Found!");
    }

    String name;
    String capital;
    String nickname;
    int population;
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        name = scan.nextLine();
        capital = scan.nextLine();
        nickname = scan.nextLine();
        population = scan.nextInt();
        if(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
          String dummy = scan.nextLine();   
        }


        State state = new State(name, capital, nickname, population);
        states.add(state);
    }



}
}
```

State class

```
 public class State implements Comparable
 {
// instance variables
private String name;
private String capital;
private String nickname;
private int population;

public State(String n, String c, String nn, int p)
{
    name = n;
    capital = c;
    nickname = nn;
    population = p;
}


    public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getCapital()
{
    return capital;
}

public String getNickname()
{
    return nickname;
}

public int getPopulation()
{
    return population;
}

// Comparable Interface method
// Casts obj to a String, then calls the String class's
// compareTo method to compare the name of this state
// to the name passed in the parameter list. It returns
// either a positive number, negative number, or zero.

@Override
public int compareTo(Object otherState) 
{
   String otherName = ((State)otherState).getName();

   return name.compareTo(otherName);
}

}
```

I am aware that the formatting is atrocious. However on line 73 and 85, I am struggling to resolve an error in which it states, "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to State". I know that the error is caused by the fact that the return type of the method is State. However I can not change it to int because in line 35, my state variable is set to Class type which will return an error if the binarySearch method type is changed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more easily and more quickly if you provide a [mcve]. The code you give should produce the exact error message that you are asking about. As it stands, we do not have the `State` class.

Comment: Also, what are lines 85 and 73? I can't count that high.

Comment: Line 73: "Return midpoint";  Line 85: "Return -1;"

Comment: Also added the State class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the following function signature:

```
public State binarySearch(String key)
```

The says that you must return an object of type `State`, but you return values which are of type `int` with `return midpoint;` and return -1;`. The easiest fix is to change the signature to

```
public int binarySearch(String key)
```

Another solution is to leave the method signature as it is and return the `State` object at the given index. Instead of

```
return midpoint;
```

do

```
return states.get(midpoint);
```

And instead of

```
return -1;
```

do

```
return null;
```

While it is possible to return a `-1` or a `State` as the comments for `binarySearch()` suggest, it is not a good idea because these have two different types.

Comment: Changing the signature does resolve the errors in line 73 and 85. However at line 35("State state = binarySearch(stateName);"), the error "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to State" appears.

Comment: @LudiCrudi What does the value returned by `binarySearch()` represent? How can you use it to get a `State` object?